# how to import local package files in my main package?

Tags: flutter, import, package, sip, flutter-webrtc

[image]

I want to import the about.dart file in my main.dart file. But it is showing error while I'm copying its path. I tried many ways to import it, but all fails. Can anyone please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

if both the files are in the same folder you can import them using this line

```
import './dialpad.dart';
```

if you want to import the file from a folder at the same level of the file in which you want to import you can use this line

```
import '../widgets/some_file.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

To use your local package you have to define package and give a package `path` inside your `pubspec.yaml` for the package.

To add local package in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
  sip_up-0.5.6:
    path: ./sip_up-0.5.6
```

Comment: It's not working, It is giving error while I'm trying to do this.